# Call a function with an argument in Google app's newTrigger("myFunction")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to call a function with an argument in Google app's `newTrigger()` function.

I have a function called `writeToSheet(sheet)`. Where as I enter the sheet name into the argument and the custom output is written to said sheet. It all works fine, but I would like to pass this into a time driven trigger with different sheets being written to at different times.

So far, entering `ScriptApp.newTrigger('writeToSheet("Production Sheet")')` within Google's trigger building example doesn't work. How would you go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have had to create a function that executes what I need.

```
function prodSheetUpdate() {
  writeToSheets("Production Sheet");
}
```

Then pass that function in my trigger.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("ProdSheetUpdate")
 ...
 ...
```

It doesn't seem like you can pass an argument in a trigger. If anybody knows otherwise, I am still curious!

Answer (score -1):

you must pass a string to `newTrigger`

`ScriptApp.newTrigger('writeToSheet('+'Production Sheet'+')')`

or

`var mystring 
ScriptApp.newTrigger('writeToSheet('+mystring+')')`

Comment: sorry, var mystring =  'Production Sheet'
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('writeToSheet('+mystring+')')